# Teams app not showing on my mobile device

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, appsource

> I have published my teams app few days back and I've installed it on my desktop app, it is visible on every browser but not in teams mobile app.

Comment: I got this reference and as per this, it may upto 24 hrs to show app on mobile clients but in my case it has been over 3 days but still it is not visible- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/design/tabs-mobile

Comment: I have also noticed that there are many such apps which is installed and visible on browsers and desktop clients but not on mobile clients. So please let me the reason if there's any criteria to show apps on mobile clients because I didn't find any such references.